# (Using a custom function to) Sum above N rows in a datatable (dataframe) by groups

Tags: r, datatable, sapply

I need a function that sums the above N+1 rows in dataframes (data tables) by groups.

An equivalent function for a *vector*, would be something like below. (Please forgive me if the function below is inefficient)

```
Function1<-function(x,N){
  y<-vector(length=length(x))
for (i in 1:length(x))
if (i<=N) 
  y[i]<-sum(x[1:i])
else if (i>N) 
  y[i]<-sum(x[(i-N):i])
return(y)}

Function1(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),3)
#[1] 1 3 6 10 14 18 # Sums previous (above) 4 values (rows)
```

I wanted to use this function with sapply, like below..

```
sapply(X=DF<-data.frame(A=c(1:10), B=2), FUN=Function1(N=3))
```

but couldn't.. because I could not figure out how to set a default for the x in my function. Thus, I built another function for data.frames.

```
Function2<-function(x, N)
 if(is.data.frame(x)) {
y<-data.frame()
for(j in 1:ncol(x))
  for(i in 1:nrow(x))
    if (i<=N) {
      y[i,j]<-sum(x[1:i,j])
    }   else if (i>N)  {
      y[i,j]<-sum(x[(i-N):i,j])}
return(y)}

DF<-data.frame(A=c(1:10), B=2)
Function2(DF, 2)
#   V1 V2
1   1  2
2   3  4
3   6  6
4   9  6
5  12  6
6  15  6
7  18  6
8  21  6
9  24  6
10 27  6
```

However, I still need to perform this by groups. For example, for the following data frame with a character column.

```
DF<-data.frame(Name=rep(c("A","B"),each=5), A=c(1:10), B=2)
```

I would like to apply my function by group "Name" -- which would result in.

```
A   1  2
A   3  4
A   6  6
A   9  6
A  12  6
B   6  2
B  13  4
B  21  6
B  24  6
B  27  6


#Perform function2 separately for group A and B.
```

I was hoping to use function with the data.table package (by=Groups), but couldn't figure out how.

What would be the best way to do this?
(Also, it would be really nice, if I could learn how to make my Function1 to work in sapply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, we group by 'Name', loop through the columns of interest specified in `.SDcols` (here all the columns are of interest so we are not specifying it) and apply the `Function1`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, lapply(.SD, Function1, 2), Name]
#    Name  A B
# 1:    A  1 2
# 2:    A  3 4
# 3:    A  6 6
# 4:    A  9 6
# 5:    A 12 6
# 6:    B  6 2
# 7:    B 13 4
# 8:    B 21 6
# 9:    B 24 6
#10:    B 27 6
```